# Google map api issues with Iphone seacrh

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my app I am using google map api to add locations for users. Everything is working fine apart from IOS being a bit tough.

In google maps when I search using the google map search input field it shows me the list of locations using its auto complete but when I try to select one from the list it fails.

This can be seen here http://www.demo.tippnett.no/. The login credentials are 
**user578@example.com** and **123qwe**.

After logging in, click *Legg til nytt prosjekt*. It will take you to the search field. Search something there and try to select on location from the auto complete.

On Iphone it will not select anything. Is this a known issue?

This is how I am adding search plugin

```
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox((input));
google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function () {
   alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Are you testing on iOs 8 or 7 ? Or all of them have the same outcome ?

Comment: All of them are having same issue.

Comment: Try data-tap-disabled='true' on your map

Comment: Where do I add this? In map options?

Comment: On the map holder or try to add an event listener for tapping on the box and see if that works, just alert something to start with

Comment: I added <div id="map-canvas" class="map_canvas" data-tap-disabled='true'></div>, it didn't worked.

Comment: You need to add it dinamically after the map loaded, otherwise try my second suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81621/discussion-between-chaudhry-mohsin-ali-and-lau).

Comment: The conflicting part is foundation. When I remove foundation it starts to work fine.

Comment: But I still have to find how to use both.